# passing id to ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor, webmatrix

I have a link like this
`<a class="viewp" href="#">@data.name</a>`

and I would like to call a jquery ajax this way

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.viewp').click(function (id)
        {
            var responseUrl="~/click?id="+id;                    
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                data:id,
                url:responseUrl,
                success:success
            });
        });
    });
```

But I don't know how the `id` of the `@data.name` is passed into the jquery function.
If I replace the above link's `href` with `href="~/click?id=@data.id"`
then that is supposed to load the whole page not some specific region and clearly ajax doesn't work also.

[**UPDATE**]

By `id` I would mean the `id` primary key of my sql table and I am using webmatrix to code my simple web page. My database table looks like this `create table x(id, name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't got what exactly you mean

if it is like

< a class="viewp" href="#" id="someId" >@data.name< /a>

if you want to get id of it

then

$(this).attr("id");

if you want to get text @data.name

then

$(this).text();

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<a id="@data.id" class="viewp" href="#">@data.name</a>
```

And then in the function you can get the id:

```
$('.viewp').click(function()
{
    var id = this.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this)` to get the currently clicked a tag and then get the `id` attribute value of that.

```
 $('.viewp').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");   
    var responseUrl="~/click?id="+id 
     //do your ajax call here
 });
```